# Stacktrace reported by UnhandledExceptionEventArgs exception becomes null after extracting once

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 RT application. In the app, I subscribe to `UnhandledException` event which is raised when any unhandled exception occurs in the application. I bind this event to an event handler, which is passed `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` by the event.

`UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` has a property `Exception`, which has a property `Stacktrace`. The problem is, I'm only able to access the stacktrace property **only once**, as it becomes null after I access it.

This weird behavior can also be observed when any breakpoint is hit and you try to access the value contained in the argument using the cursor or the immediate window. Once I hover the cursor or access the value in the immediate window, it becomes null afterwards.

It also causes an issue when I read any property of `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` before reading the `Stacktrace` property. Say, if `e` is of type `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` containing `Message` and `Exception` object, accessing `e.Message` before accessing `e.Exception.Stacktrace` makes the value contained in `e.Exception.Stacktrace` null.

Any idea why this odd behavior is observed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case, but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception) says:

> The UnhandledException event arguments expose an exception object
>   through the Exception property. However, the type, message, and stack
>   trace of this exception object are not guaranteed to match those of
>   the original exception that was raised

Comment: I'm aware of the limitations mentioned there, but I guess that is not the problem in this case. If the exposed exception object has a stacktrace, it should be available for access. The stacktrace is not visible long enough. The message and type persist, but the stacktrace becomes null after a single access.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue: [Improper WinRT exception behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100603/improper-winrt-exception-behavior)

You should save **UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Exception** value to a variable before reading any properties of **UnhandledExceptionEventArgs** class.
After that you can access any information (like stack trace) at any moment by reading your variable value(not **UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Exception** value).

Answer (score -1):

Try use property *UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Message*

Compare

```
Application.Current.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString()); // {"Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."}
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Exception.Message); // "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Message); // "System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.\r\n   at AppMetrica.Demo.MainPage.<>c.<.ctor>b__0_2(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)"
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately args.Message doesn't always contain the stacktrace